# iOS 8 Health data: backup and iCloud

Tags: backup, health.app

I hat to bring in my iPhone for repair and I backed up all the data on iCloud and with iTunes (just to be sure). I then got a replacement phone for one week.

I was not able to recover my Health data:

- The data seems not to be synchronised with iCloud (no other device as my iPad or the replacement phone see anything)
- The data was not backed up. I got everything back but for the Health data

Is there a way to back Health data up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need to encrypt your iPhone backups for your local backups to retain health data:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6357

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks! The local backup was not encrypted (as the whole partition is ...)

Comment: On iOS 8.2 when you go to Settings -> iCloud -> Backup it does say it automatically backup your Health data. Maybe they added this ability recently.

Comment: Has to be encrypted! Can't believe this! I've had my new phone for 2 weeks, I've tried various ways of exporting from old phone and importing to new but no joy. Anyone found a successful process?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: iOS 11.0 has an option to sync Health.app data instead of just backing it up. So now you can perform a clean install and still have your health data.

iOS 8.0 doesn't backup Health.app data to iCloud but iOS 9 does.

> You can save the information stored in your Health app by backing up
>   your iOS device with iCloud. Your information gets encrypted as it
>   goes between iCloud and your device, and while it's stored in iCloud.
>   If you aren't using iCloud, you can back up your Health information by
>   encrypting your iTunes backup.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6357

Answer (score -3):

iTunes and iCloud are good tool for iPhone data. You can backup your iphone with iCloud or iTunes. If you lost data, you can recover from them 
You can restore iTunes backups to your iPhone at any time. Follow these steps to choose a backup and sync the data to your iPhone.

1. Connect the iPhone to the computer with a USB cable.
2. Open iTunes.
3. If you have a new or erased iPhone, iTunes will prompt you to restore from backup.
4. Otherwise, Control-click on your iPhone under DEVICES in the left menu.
5. Select Restore From Backup...
6. Choose the backup you wish to sync and click the Restore button.

You will be prompted by Setup Assistant by a new iPhone to set up as a new phone or restore from backup.

Make sure your iPhone is connected to Wi-Fi and plugged into the charger.
Select the option Restore From iCloud Backup.
Enter your iCloud account and password.
Choose the recent backup you wish to restore to your iPhone.
Enter any passwords required when prompted.

Or you can use some third-party programs like Tenorshare iPhone Data Recovery, you can check it on Google

Comment: This is a general description of a backup. As stated in the question I had a backup, I was able to recover everything but 
"Health" data